# Possible to emulate a basic CTE in MySQL by in-lining it

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

There have been various questions about this but I'm not sure if they address this particular aspect of it. Let's say we have the following query on a non-recursive, non-volatile, non-depdendent CTE?

```
WITH tbl AS (
      SELECT 1 AS a
  ) SELECT * FROM tbl
```

Is it possible and valid to always replace `tbl` with a sub-select that the CTE refers to? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS a) myCTE
```

Comment: *Is it possible and valid to always replace tbl with a sub-select that the CTE refers to?* If CTE is not recursive then your transformation is correct. Moreover, you descrive the method which is used when you need to convert a query with CTE for to execute it on 5.x server. The only point - if you use CTE multiple times then you must use a lot of code copies while converting CTE to subqueries.

Comment: @Akina thanks. Does it matter if there is any volatile functions within the CTE, such as `SELECT RAND()` ? Or that is a non-issue.

Comment: There is no problem in such case if you use one copy. But when you use CTE multiple times then each code copy will generate its own RAND() value in according row.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6f8306f8d5adaf4850a9360eefbfd6e

Comment: @Akina do different SQL backends handle CTE persistence differently? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569249/why-isnt-a-cte-evaluated-one-time

Comment: I think that in those case we see not true CTE but inlined subquery which is synthactically formed as CTE. And this does not match CTE definition in general, it seems.