# Why isn't a CTE evaluated one time?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

If we take the following:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT RAND() AS a
) SELECT * FROM tbl AS tbl1, tbl AS tbl2
```

[image]

Why does this return two values instead of one? I thought a CTE is basically evaluated one time at the start and then it is used wherever it is needed? Or is my understanding of persistency of a CTE incorrect? Or does the implementation from db to db differ?

Compared with MySQL where it returns a single persisted-value:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause)

> BigQuery only materializes the results of recursive CTEs, but does not materialize the results of non-recursive CTEs inside the WITH clause. If a non-recursive CTE is referenced in multiple places in a query, then the CTE is executed once for each reference.

So what you see is expected at least for BigQuery.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Would that be considered a non-standard/ANSI implementation of a CTE, or is it not specified?