# How to emulate a dependent CTE

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

Following up from this question [Possible to emulate a basic CTE in MySQL by in-lining it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569224/possible-to-emulate-a-basic-cte-in-mysql-by-in-lining-it), would it be possible to in-line the following query in mysql5.7 without the usage of CTEs?

```
WITH tbl1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS a
), tbl2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2
), tbl3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 USING (a)
) SELECT * FROM tbl3, tbl2
```

If so, how could that be done?

Comment: If there is no non-deterministic constructions in your CTEs or if such CTEs are used once then simply replace CTEs names with their subqueries nestedly. If non-deterministic constructions are present, and according CTE must be used more than once then temporarily created (not temporary!) tables for these CTEs is the only option.

Comment: @Akina could you please clarify what you mean by: `then temporarily created (not temporary!) tables for these CTEs is the only option`. How would you create a temporarily-created table equivalent for `WITH cte AS (SELECT RAND() AS a)...` ?

Comment: As separate `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` query.

Comment: @Akina sure, but how's that different than a tmp table? Anyways, it'd be destroyed after usage so I suppose it's a non-issue.

Comment: Temporary table cannot be used more than once in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particular problem with doing that, except that you have to repeat tbl2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS a
    ) tbl1
    JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2
    ) tbl2
    USING (a)
) tbl3
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2
) tbl2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8f4f3f53d66228cb7b7b998bfab3c0e4)

Answer (score 0):

This would be similar to substituting the body of a function. Writing it in a similar way (conceptually speaking):

```
let tbl1 =  (SELECT 1 AS a)                          AS tbl1
let tbl2 =  (SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2)       AS tbl2
let tbl3 =  (SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 USING (a)) AS tbl3
-- rewriting tbl1 for tbl1 and tbl2
let tbl3 =  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS a) AS tbl1 
             JOIN ((SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2)) AS tbl1 USING (a)) AS tbl3


SELECT * FROM tbl3, tbl2
-- substitutie for tbl3, tbl2
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS a) AS tbl1 
              JOIN ((SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2)) AS tbl1 USING (a)) AS tbl3,
    (SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS tbl2
```